# Verifying Green's Theorem for two functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, greens-theorem

> Verify Green's theorem for the functions: $M(x,y)=2x^3+y^3$ and $N(x,y)=3xy^2$, and the region $D$ which is the annulus between the circles of radii $a$ and $b$ ($a<b$), centered at the origin. Be careful with the orientations.

I am aware of Green's theorem but am not sure how to approach and proceed with this problem. I don't know how to set up the integral and I am very confused. Help would be greatly appreciated! Please and thank you!

Comment: Hint: write two contour/line/path integrals in opposite directions.

Comment: @SeanRoberson can you help me do this? I am completely lost. I know what line integrals are but we never covered it in depth. Please help!

Comment: maybe check out Paul's Online Math Notes regarding Calculus 3 and Green's theorem in particular...

Answer (score 2):

You need to show that 
$$
    \int_{\partial D} (M\,dx + N\,dy)
    = \iint_{D} \left(\frac{\partial N}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial M}{\partial y}\right)\,dA
$$

For the right-hand side:
\begin{align*}
    \frac{\partial N}{\partial x} &=6xy \\
    \frac{\partial M}{\partial y} &=3y^2 \\
\end{align*}
So 
\begin{align*}
    \iint_{D} \left(\frac{\partial N}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial M}{\partial y}\right)\,dA
    &= \iint_D \left(6xy-3y^2\right)\,dA \\
    &= \int_0^{2\pi} \int_a^b 6\left((r \cos \theta)(r\sin\theta) - 3(r\sin\theta)^2\right)\,r\,dr\,d\theta
\end{align*}
For the left-hand side, let $C_a$ and $C_b$ be the circles of radius $a$ and $b$ centered at the origin.  Then as oriented curves, $\partial D = C_b - C_a$.  We can parametrize $C_a$ by $x=a\cos\theta$, $y=a\sin\theta$, $0 \leq\theta\leq 2\pi$, and similarly for $C_b$.  Therefore
\begin{align*}
    \int_{\partial D} \left(M\,dx + N\,dy\right)
    &= \int_0^{2\pi}\left(\left(2(b\cos\theta)^3 +(b\sin\theta)^3\right)(-b\sin\theta) + \left(3(b\cos\theta)(b\sin\theta)^2\right)(b\cos\theta)\right)\,d\theta \\
    &\qquad-\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\left((a\cos\theta)^3 +(a\sin\theta)^3\right)(-a\sin\theta) + \left(3(a\cos\theta)(a\sin\theta)^2\right)(a\cos\theta)\right)\,d\theta
\end{align*}
Evaluate each and show that they are equal.